# Cloning repository from ruby

Tags: ruby, git, sinatra

I'm creating a Sinatra app that will pull in data from a remote git repository.

I've taken a look at the [ruby-git](https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git) gem, but I get `cannot load such file -- git` on the line of `require 'git'`. The gem is installed and in my Gemfile.

I'm not sure if this is the correct way about going about this, but essentially I want the app to checkout a git repository for pulling in data.

Comment: Are you sure the gem is installed correctly? Or maybe something wrong with your ruby version? "gem which git" will show the info about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the system command:

```
system("git clone #{$config['repository']} content")
```